# How to get git update-index working with macOS?

Tags: macos, git

I installed git with `brew install git`

Now I want to use the **update-index** parameter, but that doesn't work because git-update-index is not installed.

How can I install this via Homebrew or another way for macOS?

**EDIT**

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with git version 2.18.0 (both currently at the time of this writing).

```
$ type -a git
git is /usr/local/bin/git
git is /usr/bin/git
```

I'll check that tomorrow on work, because with my home-mac it works the correct way.

Comment: Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/334318/edit) the question to specify the version of macOS installed on your Mac. Also mention the version of git installed (determined by running `git --version`). You can verify that you are referring to the Homebrew installed git by running `type -a git` and checking that the 1st line in the output shows `git is /usr/local/bin/git`.

Comment: Why not use the git included in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this issue is:

```
brew reinstall git
```

After that I got this:

```
➜  ~ $ ls /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.18.0/libexec/git-core/
...
git-update-index
...
```

And now the command `git update-index --assume-unchanged LocalConfiguration.php` which I initial want to use finally works.

Answer (score 0):

You are possible executing the command incorrectly. There is no `git-update-index` command.

Instead try, `git update-index`.

There is no additional steps required to install `git-update-index`.

Comment: the executable is here on my home mac: /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.18.0/libexec/git-core/git-update-index - i'll compare it tomorrow

Comment: @MonTea That's the default location for git executable installed via Homebrew.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is on my work-mac there isn't that file so the parameter update-index doesn't work.. perhaps i have to deinstall it and reinstall it again... don't know - thank you i'll report tomorrow ;)